# How to recover accidentally deleted files under MAC terminal?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I did "rm -R *" under MAC Lion terminal, and apparent the deleted files didn't go to trash. Not sure whether there is an easy way to restore them or not.

Comment: The trash can is a purely GUI-based system, and does not watch what you do in a command shell. Unless you've good at hacking low-level filesystem internals, the files are gone.

Comment: stackexchange clearly needs a "best of" voting feature, like Craigslist. :)  You have been hereby initiated into Unix.

Comment: Not seeing a programming question here.

Comment: I suppose you don't have time machine hooked up there?

Comment: The thing is that I deleted files under '/Volumes/...', which is a network place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use testdisk/photorec to recover the files. It's free and open source, and works fairly well. If you have homebrew installed, it's as easy as

`brew install testdisk`

Edit: Just realized, this is offtopic.

Comment: `photorec` isn’t in homebrew, and as far as I can see from the repo, never was.